# Symbol not found for x86_x64 when add GPUImage framework ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, frameworks, gpuimage, arm64

I see the many of the stackoverflow questions and answers related to my question but,I don't found the perfect solution for this . In some cases I add the

1> Header search path .

2> Other linker flags. (**-ObjC**)

3> Valid Architectures (**armv7 , armv7s , arm64**)

but i don't understand what the path of **Header Search Path**..I upload the screenshot of the errors.
[image]

**Note :** It **works** on **iphone 4 and 5** (32bit) but, It **doesn't work** on **iphone 4 , 5 ,(64 bit) , 6** and **6+**

please help me..for this I am trying to solve this problem since last five days.

Thanks.

Comment: Run it on a real device, I think x86_x64 is for simulator.

Comment: In real device it works or not..?

Comment: I am afraid I don't know, you can try it out by yourself.

Comment: did you see this tutorial http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/build-a-photo-app-with-gpuimage--mobile-12223 ? Especially Step 7: Add GPUImage to Your Project

Comment: Yes , I try this also but, it doesn't work.

Comment: I think you can drag the GPUImage.xcodeproj project to your project and it will build the source code when you run your project, remember to set the header search path properly with recursive mode.

Comment: But what the path of "header search path"..I can't understand.

Comment: You can download the sample projects from Github of GPUImage and check out the way they specify the header search path, and mimic what they do.